# Python Sympy bool_map bug with xor/xnor?

Tags: dictionary, boolean, python-3.5, sympy

Python3.5 Sympy seems to think Xor and Xnor are equivalent?

This code in python3.5:

```
from sympy import *
A1,A2 = symbols('A1,A2')
f1 = Xor(A1,A2)
f2 = ~(Xor(A1,A2))
print(bool_map(f2,f1))
print(bool_map(f1,f2))
```

Results in this output:

```
((A1 & A2) | (~A1 & ~A2), {A1: A1, A2: A2})
((A1 & ~A2) | (A2 & ~A1), {A1: A1, A2: A2})
```

So the simplified logic for f1 and f2 are clearly different, yet bool_map still returned with it considered a valid symbol mapping for the 2 boolean equations?

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit:** This is indeed a bug

This is a flaw in the _finger 5-item fingerprint:

```
'''
Assign a 5-item fingerprint to each symbol in the equation:
[
# of times it appeared as a Symbol,
# of times it appeared as a Not(symbol),
# of times it appeared as a Symbol in an And or Or,
# of times it appeared as a Not(Symbol) in an And or Or,
sum of the number of arguments with which it appeared,
counting Symbol as 1 and Not(Symbol) as 2
]
'''
from sympy import *
from sympy.logic.boolalg import _finger
from collections import defaultdict
from pprint import pprint

A1,A2 = symbols('A1,A2')
a = _finger((A1 & A2) | (~A1 & ~A2))
b = _finger((A1 & ~A2) | (~A1 & A2))

pprint(a)
pprint(b)
```

results in identical fingerprints for A1 and A2:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {(0, 0, 1, 1, 6): [A1, A2]})
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {(0, 0, 1, 1, 6): [A1, A2]})
```

which is why A1 and A2 appear interchangeable

Comment: Perhaps the only thing you did wrong was posting here instead of SymPy repo; bug reports logically belong there. But I see you [reported it already](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/15171).  Without reading the source, I guess the issue is that f1 becomes equivalent to f2 if A1 is replaced by `~A1` which confuses `bool_map` somewhere.

Comment: The reported issue has been resolved in SymPy.